# Adding Size Constraints for Views inside a UIStackView

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uistackview

I currently have a UIStackView that I add views to, it fits a maximum of 10 views along with a button. The issue however, is that although the views I add are equal size, the button is not.

I have tried adding a constraint that determines sets the button's equal to 1/11th of the StackViewSize (so that all of the views can fit equally), but it just seems to break all the other constraints.

How can I give the button size without breaking a million constraints?

Currently the height of the button is adjusted with each new view added, but that's just ugly.

Comment: A little tough to understand exactly what you're trying to do. Add a couple images to your question - one with how it currently looks, and one with how you *want* it to look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, set height and width to that button according to your requirement using AutoLayout. Then select your stack view from the Document Outline(in your view controllers hierarchy) & then in Attribute Inspector set its Distribution to 'Fill Proportionally'. Add some spacing if you want.